# cannot find autoconf. please check your autoconf installation Xampp in CentOS

Tags: php, centos, xampp, memcached, autoconf

Getting another error when configuring memcahed with php in XAMPP in CentOS

```
#  /opt/lampp/bin/phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20131106
Zend Module Api No:      20131226
Zend Extension Api No:   220131226
```

> **Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation** and
>   the
>       $PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

How to resolved it ?

Answer (score 137):

**MAC Users**

You can do it easily using brew.

> `brew install autoconf`

Comment: This way is specially recommended for MacOSX users.

Comment: Works also with MacPorts: `port install autoconf`.

Answer (score 86):

I got here looking for an answer for **docker** when using **Alpine linux** this worked for me (I tried @Dimitros solution but did not work):

```
RUN apk --no-cache add pcre-dev ${PHPIZE_DEPS} \ 
  && pecl install xdebug \
  && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
  && apk del pcre-dev ${PHPIZE_DEPS}
```

Comment: This works! just don't forget to follow docker image's documentation `It is strongly recommended that users use an explicit version number in their pecl install invocations to ensure proper PHP version compatibility`

Comment: Im still getting errors: The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache pcre-dev ${PHPIZE_DEPS}   && pecl install xdebug-2.6.0   && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug   && apk del pcre-dev ${PHPIZE_DEPS}' returned a non-zero code: 4

Comment: For me this was enough: `apk --no-cache add autoconf g++ make && pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug && rm -rf /tmp/pear; apk del autoconf g++ make;` in  `php:8.0.2-alpine` docker image

Comment: @piotrekkr Thanks! This solution works great within a container of the docker-image php:8.0.20RC1-zts-alpine3.16

Answer (score 61):

You need to install autoconf

For CentOS:

```
# yum install autoconf
```

for Ubuntu :

```
# apt-get install autoconf
```

for fedora 24-27:

```
   # dnf install autoconf
```

Comment: This saved me a lot of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 40):

For Alpine Linux the `apk add` feature has (for cleanup) a concept of virtual packages using the `--virtual` or `-t` switch. An example use of this would be removing a group of build dependencies all at once:

```
apk add --no-cache --update --virtual buildDeps autoconf \
 && pecl install xdebug \
 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
 && apk del buildDeps
```

Reference: https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/master/docs/usage.md

Answer (score 1):

For openSuSE:

```
zypper install autoconf
```

Answer (score -1):

I resolved the problem by  "yum install  autoconf" on CentOS 7

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer, please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions. Make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.