# Failed loading /usr/lib/php7/modules/xdebug.so: Error relocating /usr/lib/php7/modules/xdebug.so: php_sprintf: symbol not found

Tags: xdebug

we are trying to install XDebug inside a Docker container based on Alpine Linux and running php-fpm. We followed the installation instructions given at [this](https://xdebug.org/docs/install) page. It says to run following for Alpine Linux which is what we did:

```
bash-5.0# apk add php7-pecl-xdebug
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/2) Installing php7-common (7.3.22-r0)
(2/2) Installing php7-pecl-xdebug (2.9.1-r0)
OK: 85 MiB in 74 packages
```

we could then see the `.so` file is under `/usr/lib/php7/modules/xdebug.so` and so we added it to our `/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini` like so:

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php7/modules/xdebug.so
```

Then we restarted the container. The webpage says to verify the installation by running:

```
bash-5.0# php -v
```

when we run the command this is the output we get:

```
bash-5.0# php -v
Failed loading /usr/lib/php7/modules/xdebug.so:  Error relocating /usr/lib/php7/modules/xdebug.so: php_sprintf: symbol not found
PHP 7.4.4 (cli) (built: Mar 24 2020 01:34:16) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.4, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

How can we fix this? Thanks. In case it helps:

```
bash-5.0# ls -al /usr/lib/php7/modules/xdebug.so
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        268088 Jan 18  2020 /usr/lib/php7/modules/xdebug.so
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this error comes from some C library that is not installed on the system. We performed following steps from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48444443/147530) answer and it worked. It also installs latest version of `xdebug` (version 3.0.2). `apk add php7-pecl-xdebug` was installing version 2.9 of `xdebug`.

Step 1: Install dependencies:

```
apk --no-cache add pcre-dev ${PHPIZE_DEPS}
```

Step 2: Build binary from sources:

```
pecl install xdebug
```

On success it should end with

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/xdebug-3.0.2
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so" to php.ini
```

Step 3: Now edit `php.ini` and set `zend_extension` to path given above

Step 4: Verify

```
bash-5.0# php -v
PHP 7.4.4 (cli) (built: Mar 24 2020 01:34:16) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.4, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: In my case I didn't have to add the extension to php.ini, You can verify that by calling this command: `php -v` If You will get something like: `with Xdebug v3.1.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans` as one of the output line, then You should be good.