# Adding redis extension in PHP Dockerfile causes installation fail

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, redis

I want to add Redis extension in PHP dockerfile from API Platform repository ([link](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/blob/main/api/Dockerfile))
So, i've added this following command :

```yaml
RUN pecl install -o -f redis \
    &&  rm -rf /tmp/pear \
    &&  docker-php-ext-enable redis
```

(based on solutions found on stackoverflow answers) but when i'm building with `docker-compose build` i have error below :

```
 > [app-php php_base  5/14] RUN pecl install -o -f redis &&  rm -rf /tmp/pear &&  docker-php-ext-enable redis:
#0 2.750 downloading redis-6.0.2.tgz ...
#0 2.750 Starting to download redis-6.0.2.tgz (365,966 bytes)
#0 2.750 ..........................................................................done: 365,966 bytes
#0 3.176 43 source files, building
#0 3.176 running: phpize
#0 3.180 Configuring for:
#0 3.180 PHP Api Version:         20220829
#0 3.180 Zend Module Api No:      20220829
#0 3.180 Zend Extension Api No:   420220829
#0 3.193 Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
#0 3.193 $PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.
#0 3.193 
#0 3.193 ERROR: `phpize' failed
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pecl install -o -f redis &&  rm -rf /tmp/pear &&  docker-php-ext-enable redis" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

How can i fix it ? Or is there an other way to adding redis extension ?
Thank you for answers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot find autoconf. please check your autoconf installation Xampp in CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583646/cannot-find-autoconf-please-check-your-autoconf-installation-xampp-in-centos)

Comment: Effectively, these answers looks like the one i found :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with :

```
RUN apk --no-cache add \
    autoconf \
    g++ \
    make \
    && pecl install -o -f redis \
    && rm -rf /tmp/pear \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis
```